# Understanding Array Access (Processing)

Tags: java, arrays, processing

Hi could anybody help me understand this particular piece of code from this Langton's Ant sketch.

```
antLoc = new int[]{rows/2,columns/2};
```

I don't exactly understand what is actually happening here, here is the rest of the code for context. (originally from here http://www.openprocessing.org/visuals/?visualID=13653)

```
boolean[][] state;
int[] antLoc;
int antDirection;

int squareSize = 5;
int columns, rows;

color bgCol = color(0,128,128);
color antCol = color (255,0,0);
color sqCol = color(128,128,128);

void setup(){
  size(800,600);
  background(bgCol);
  columns = width/squareSize;
  rows = height/squareSize;

  state = new boolean[rows][columns];
  for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++){
    for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++){
      state[j][i] = false;
    }
  }
  antLoc = new int[]{rows/2,columns/2};
  antDirection = 1;
}

void drawScene(){
  fill(sqCol);
  for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++){
    for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++){
      if(state[j][i]){
        rect(i*squareSize,j*squareSize,squareSize,squareSize);
      }
    }
  }
  fill(antCol);
  rect(antLoc[1]*squareSize,antLoc[0]*squareSize,squareSize,squareSize);
}

void turnLeft(){
  if (antDirection > 1){
    antDirection--;
  } else{
    antDirection = 4;
  }
}

void turnRight(){
  if (antDirection < 4){
    antDirection++;
  } else {
    antDirection = 1;
  }
}

void moveForward(){
  if (antDirection == 1){
    antLoc[0]--;
  }
  if (antDirection == 2){
    antLoc[1]++;
  }
  if (antDirection == 3){
    antLoc[0]++;
  }
  if (antDirection == 4){
    antLoc[1]--;
  }
}

void updateScene(){
  moveForward();
  if (state[antLoc[0]][antLoc[1]] == false){
    state[antLoc[0]][antLoc[1]] = true;
    turnRight();
  } else {
    state[antLoc[0]][antLoc[1]] = false;
    turnLeft();
  }
}

void draw(){
  background(bgCol);
  drawScene();
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      updateScene();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you mention:

```
antLoc = new int[]{rows/2,columns/2};
```

is broadly similar to:

```
antLoc = new int[2];
antLoc[0] = rows / 2;
antLoc[1] = columns / 2;
```

It's just syntactic shorthand, for convenience.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! That makes a lot more sense, my next question was going to be how this works:

  if (state[antLoc[0]][antLoc[1]] == false)

but I think I get it now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your code creates a new array of `int` with length 2, and initialises the elements with the given expressions. It is equivalent to:

```
antLoc = new int[2];
antLoc[0] = rows/2;
antLoc[1] = columns/2;
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply!